PowerBI Headcount Chart
Looking for assistance in charting a rolling 12 month headcount chart where start dates and termination dates are given per person. So for instance if last month was Sep 24, I would count all employees then subtract count of Terminations before Sep 24 and also subtract New Hires after or equal to Sep 24.

Here is some sample data with 3 columns (Start Date or Hire Date) and End Date (or Termination Date)



Staff ID
Start Date
End Date




1001572
16/09/24



1001573
16/09/24



1001574
09/09/24



1001575
09/09/24



1001576
26/08/24



1000812
19/08/24
23/09/24


1001577
19/08/24



1001578
12/08/24



1001579
08/08/24



1001580
05/08/24



1001581
05/08/24



1001582
01/08/24



1001583
29/07/24



1001584
22/07/24



1001585
15/07/24



1000818
08/07/24
02/08/24


1001586
01/07/24



1001587
01/07/24



1001588
17/06/24



1000816
11/06/24
08/08/24


1001589
11/06/24



1001590
03/06/24



1001591
27/05/24



1001592
13/05/24



1001593
06/05/24



1001594
06/05/24



1001595
01/05/24



1001596
29/04/24



1001597
29/04/24



1001598
29/04/24



1001599
29/04/24



1001600
29/04/24



1001601
29/04/24



1001602
29/04/24



1001603
29/04/24



1000834
22/04/24
17/05/24


1000839
22/04/24
26/04/24


1001604
22/04/24



1001605
22/04/24



1001606
22/04/24



1000822
16/04/24
19/07/24


1000844
15/04/24
19/04/24


1000847
15/04/24
15/04/24


1001607
15/04/24



1001608
15/04/24



1001609
15/04/24



1001610
08/04/24



1001611
02/04/24



1001612
25/03/24



1001613
25/03/24



1001614
18/03/24



1001615
18/03/24



1001616
18/03/24



1001617
18/03/24



1001618
13/03/24



1001619
13/03/24



1001620
13/03/24



1001621
13/03/24



1001622
13/03/24



1001623
04/03/24



1001624
04/03/24




I am just getting started in PowerBI and would have no issues in Excel, but DAX is new to me

First I created a simple date table:
_Date Table = CALENDAR(MIN('Table'[Start Date]), MAX('Table'[End Date]))

Note: Do NOT make a relationship between your date table and your main table.
Then I created this measure:
Head Count = 
VAR thisDate = SELECTEDVALUE('_Date Table'[Date])

VAR HiredBefore = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table')
                    , FILTER('Table'
                        , 'Table'[Start Date] <= thisDate
                        )
)

VAR FiredBefore = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table')
                    , FILTER('Table'
                        , 'Table'[End Date] <= thisDate
                        && 'Table'[End Date] <> BLANK()
                        )
)

RETURN HiredBefore - FiredBefore

Then I created a line chart with '_Date Table'[Date] in the x-axis and Head Count in the y-axis:


A good option can be, you transform your data into daily data per customer. To do that, you can follow this below steps-

First fill the End Date column with Today() where there is no End Date available.

Then generate daily data per staff based on date range Start and End date.


Now you can introduce different charts for this transformed data.

Thank You! that's looks very close to the output I was looking for. How can I count the values at the last day of each month? And instead of a continuous line, have one line for last 12 months, called This Year, and another line showing the previous year's month called Last Year? Eg say for Oct, a will see one data point for This Year and another data point for the prior Oct

You can then keep rows only where Date = MonthEnd(Date). This will only keep records for all month's end. Regarding this and previous year line, you have to handle them in the Measure/DAX.
